# Using ScrollPath from JoelB - How to end scroll at last image

Tags: jquery, scroll

Im trying to end the scroll path at the last div(image) using this plugin "http://joelb.me/scrollpath/". Does anyone know how I could stop the scrolling at the last image, but allow user to scroll backward still?

To be slightly more specific; I want the canvas to stop at the last image forcing user to scroll back up, or click "Enter website" as my scrollpath page is a splash page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!!

In the attributes of the last image, change the .arc, .lineTo, or .moveTo properties to a .moveTo its own coordinates. The coordinates will match the style.css; however, the minus sign needs to be swapped:

demo.js-

from:

```
// Arc and rotate back to the beginning.
.arc(1300, 50, 900, -Math.PI/2, -Math.PI, true, {rotate: Math.PI*2, name: "end"});
```

to:

```
// Arc and rotate back to the beginning.
//.arc(1300, 50, 900, -Math.PI/2, -Math.PI, true, {rotate: Math.PI*2, name: "end"}); .moveTo(1150,-900);
```

In the example above the .moveTo(1150,-900) represents the coordinates of its own image providing a loop unless the user scrolls back up. The coordinates were found in the style.css:

```
.follow {
    width: 475px;
    left: 900px;
    top: -1150px;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(50px);
}
```

Notice the left & top coordinates match with the minus sign swapped.

Answer (score 1):

just set `wrapAround:false` 
Which looks like this

$(".wrapper").scrollPath({drawPath: true, **wrapAround: false**});